# Stuck on Texture Artifacts

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, normal-map, artifacts

**Important to note** I had to bake five different pieces separately for my object because no matter how I made the bake cage I kept getting poor results with one cage for the whole object (Maybe someone has a better solution??) This does result in a beautiful result except for in certain areas. The issues appear where the different normal maps meet. I have tried combining normal maps onto one material, this doesn't work. I have used a combine normal map plugin which does an amazing job on what it is supposed to do (the produced normal map literally looks like I made them all at once) but I still get artifacts. I have tried the clone brush which does nothing. I also have already merged by distance with the mesh after I joined the objects. Does anyone have a possible solution? Thanks :( I have been stuck for a long time with this maybe a week. Thanks to whoever can help or try. Just looking for a solution doesn't matter how it is done.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Credit to Polytoots on youtube, learned the following from his tutorial.

I was able to solve the artifacts by editing the normal maps. I exported the normal maps and opened them in GIMP to use a clone brush to clean up sites of distortion. (any image editor can work, I encourage one with a clone brush :)

A normal map example that I did (same principle for all of them)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi. Please help us making this site a real knowledgebase and add all relevant steps to your answer. If the link goes down so does the answer. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake sir! It will take me a bit of time but I will create a very clear explanation in layman's term! :)

Comment: My mistake and apologies everyone, I fixed it :)